# Does Lucy create the human race while touching the ape Lucy?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucy

In the movie *Lucy* from 2014.

She sort of time traveled and touched the ape which is also called Lucy.
Is it possible that she manipulated this ape to be able to control more of her own brain.

In further consequence it means that she make it possible for herself to exist.

Did I forget something or overlook something?

**edit:** apart of the thinking that she "only portraying the views". In my opinion this could also be a view of this movie or a meaning of it or not?

Comment: Related: [Did Lucy travel time or was her mind imagining / portraying the views?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/25116/49)

Answer (score 3):

This scene is reminiscent of the 2001 Space Odyssey where prehistoric ape like man touches a mysterious "flash drive" shaped obelisk beginning the evolution of mankind.  Morgan Freeman's thesis states that once the mind expands beyond 20% not only would you have control of yourself but also control of others, which would infer that she would be able to manipulate prehistoric Lucy at some evolutionary level.  In the end she texts "I am everywhere" which means she has omnipresence which infers that time is no real hurdle for her. If you are willing to assume Freeman's thesis and that she is omnipresent then yes it is possible. Of course this opens you up for all sorts of time paradoxes if you believe that time is linear.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found, or giving us the rationale behind your ideas and conclusions. I hope you enjoy participating.